# Create checkbox dynamically with weight attribute

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-gridlayout

I want to create checkboxes in java with for loop. i want to add it in gridlayout.
my problem is that checkbox take only wrap content size. I want that they should cover full width.
I can easily get it in xml like this.

```
<GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:columnCount="2">
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="dfdfdffddfd"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="dfdfdffddfd"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="dfdfdffddfd"/>
        </GridLayout>
```

but i want add these like this

```
  <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:columnCount="2">


        </GridLayout>
```

and Java code

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");
        cb.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        cb.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        checkBoxLayout.addView(cb);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
final int h = 25;
final int w = 200;
final int margin = 10;

checkBoxLayout.setColumnCount(3);
checkBoxLayout.setRowCount(1);

for( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) { 
   CheckBox check = new CheckBox( getActivity() );
   check.setText("Checkout");
   // check.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   // left, top, right, bottom
   params.setMargins(0, margin , 0, margin);
   params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
   check.setLayoutParams(params);
   check.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
   checkBoxLayout.addView(check, w, h);
}
```

Comment: the main difference is that you must add LayoutParams  to every view you create at runtime

Comment: how to  do that ?

Comment: btw i added called to setColumnCount and setRowCount check now

Comment: Sorry to say that i will have more than 3 checkboxes and i want to show only 2 horizontly .

Comment: here is working example [Insert view to GridLayout dynamically with width and height](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/09/insert-view-to-gridlayout-dynamically.html)

Comment: I Joined your movement.